# Uniqueness of Topology and Basis

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

In measure theory, we know there is a (unique) minimal $\sigma$-algebra generated by a generator. I am wondering whether this applies to topology and its basis. There are two directions to consider here.

1. Given a topology $\mathcal T$ of a set $X$, is there a unique basis for $\mathcal T$, please? If yes, how to prove it and if not, is there a simple counter-example, please?
2. Given a basis, is the topology generated by this basis unique and minimal, please? If yes, how to prove it and if not, is there a simple counter-example, please?

It seems to me that this question is basically ignored in the book I am reading. But it seems that some proofs implicitly assume something like the above. Could anyone explain this to me or direct me to useful references, please? Thank you!

Comment: Given any base for the usual topology on the reals, we can always remove any element of the base.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for your response. Then your claim implies that a topology can have many bases. Right? BTW, could you tell me where to find the proof for your claim, please? I just started learning topology a month ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$, satisfying the usual axioms:

1. $\cup \mathcal{B} = X$.
2. $\forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2: \exists B_3 \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Then we define $\mathcal{T} = \{ \cup \mathcal{O}: \mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{B} \}$, the family of all unions of subfamilies of $\mathcal{B}$. This is a topology:

a. $\emptyset = \cup \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subset \mathcal{B}$ and $X = \cup \mathcal{B}$ by axiom 1.

b. If $O_1 = \cup \mathcal{O}_1 \in \mathcal{T}$ and $O_2 = \cup \mathcal{O}_2 \in \mathcal{T}$, then for each $x \in O_1 \cap O_2$ we find $B_1 \in \mathcal{O}_1 \subset \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_1$, and $B_2 \in \mathcal{O}_2 \subset \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_2$. These $B_1, B_2$ are in $\mathcal{B}$ and $x$ is in both, so axiom 2. finds us a $B_3(x)$ such that $x \in B_3(x) \subset B_1 \cap B_2 \subset O_1 \cap O_2$. Having $B_3(x)$ for all $x \in O_1 \cap O_2$, we then define $\mathcal{O_3} = \{B_3(x): x \in O_1 \cap O_2\}$ and we see that $O_1 \cap O_2 = \cup \mathcal{O}_3$ (all members are subsets of $O_1 \cap O_2$ and each $x$ is covered by its own $B_3(x)$ at least). So $O_1 \cap O_2 \in \mathcal{T}$.

c. Suppose $I$ is an index set and for each $i \in I$ we have a set $O_i \in \mathcal{T}$, so $O_i = \cup \mathcal{O}_i \subset \mathcal{B}$. Then define $\mathcal{O} = \cup_{i \in I} \mathcal{O}_i \subset \mathcal{B}$, and we see that $\cup_{i \in I} O_i = \cup \mathcal{O}$ by associativity of unions, so $\cup_{i \in I} O_i \in \mathcal{T}$.

So we started with a collection of subsets satisfying two axioms, and we can define a topology from that. And moreover, this collection $\mathcal{B}$ does indeed form a base for this newly defined topology $\mathcal{T}$; to see this depends slightly on how you define base: by definition, all open subsets are unions from the base, or otherwise it's clear that for each $O \in \mathcal{T}$, and every $x \in O= \mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{B}$, $x$ must by definition be in one of the members of $\mathcal{B}$ from $\mathcal{O}$. So there indeed exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B \subset O$.

Also, there is no choice: if $\mathcal{T}'$ is any topology that has $\mathcal{B}$ as a base, then for any $O \in \mathcal{T'}$ we can write $O$ as a union of members of $\mathcal{B}$ (this is what being a base means!) and so $O$ is then already in our defined $\mathcal{T}$. Hence $\mathcal{T}' \subset \mathcal{T}$. The other side is also obvious: all sets in $\mathcal{B'}$ are in $\mathcal{T'}$ (base sets for a topology are themselves open in that topology) and so all unions of their subfamilies, i.e. $\mathcal{T}$, are also in $\mathcal{T}'$, as topologies are closed under unions. So $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$, and we have equality. So the topology defined by a (pregiven) base $\mathcal{B}$ is uniquely determined by that base, in the way we define above.

On the other hand, given a topology $\mathcal{T}$, there are in general lots of bases for it. Of course $\mathcal{T}$ is itself a base (trivially). But often we cam omit sets from a base, and still have a base:

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space (meaning that all singletons are closed sets). If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $X$, and $O \in \mathcal{B}$ has more than 1 point, then $\mathcal{B} \setminus \{O\}$ is also a base for $X$. First we show that $O$ can be written as a union of *proper* subsets, all from $\mathcal{B}$: pick $p \neq q$, both in $O$, which can be done by assumption. Then $O \setminus \{p\} = O \cap (X \setminus \{p\})$ is open in $X$ and thus a union of members from $\mathcal{B}$, and all of these miss $p$, so they are proper subsets of $O$. Similarly $O \setminus \{q\}$ can be so written and then we combine these two families to get what we want. So if $U$ is any open set of $X$, we can write it as a union of members of $\mathcal{B}$. If we do not use $O$, we are done, otherwise replace $O$ in this union by the proper subsets of it (from $\mathcal{B}$ as well) that union up to it, as we know we can. In all cases, we have written $U$ as a union of sets from $\mathcal{B}\setminus\{O\}$.

So from any base for $\mathbb{R}$, e.g., we can remove any open set (either such a set is empty, or it has uncountably many points) and still have a base for $\mathbb{R}$. And we can go on doing that and remove any finite number of them. Countable need not work (as there are countable bases for this topology, and we cannot remove *all* of them, of course...)

If the topology of $X$ is closed under *all* (not just finite) intersections, as happens trivially in finite spaces, but in others as well, there is a canonical minimal base: all sets $B_x = \cap \{O : O \text{ open and } x \in O \}$ must be in the base and a base consisting of all of these cannot be thinned out any further. For a discrete space e.g. this is just the base consisting of all singletons. But even in these cases, a base is not unique, but there happens to be a unique minimal one, which makes reasoning about such spaces a bit more convenient.

Comment: @HennoBransma, does space with finite weight has a canonical minimal base?

Answer (score 1):

Take the usual topology on the reals, let $B$ be a base for the topology, and let $A$ be an element of $\mathcal{B}$. We show that if we remove $A$ from $\mathcal{B}$, we will still have a base for the topology.

For every point $p\in A$, there is an open subset $A_p$ of $A$ which contains $p$ and is not all of $A$. This open subset is a union of elements of the base, and $A$ is not used in that union, since $A_p$ is not all of $A$.

Now take the union over all $p\in A$ of the sets used in forming the $A_p$. This is $A$, so $A$ is not needed.