# Basis determining a unique topology

Tags: general-topology

When I read Munkres' *Topology*, I have a feeling that if we have a basis $\mathscr{B}$ on a set $X$, then the basis determines uniquely a topology on $X$; that is, if we have two topologies $\mathscr{T}_1, \mathscr{T}_2$ with the same basis $\mathscr{B}$, then $\mathscr{T}_1=\mathscr{T}_2$. I'm not sure if I'm right because I can't see this in the definition, which is as follows:

> If $X$ is set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $X$ (called basis elements) such that for each $x\in X$, there is at least one $B\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B$ and if $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, where $B_1, B_2\in \mathscr{B}$, then there exists $B_3\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$.

Moreover, the basis $\mathscr{B}$ generates a topology

> $\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{B}=\left\{ U\subset X: \text{for each $x\in U$, there exists $B\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subset U$}\right\}$,

which is the smallest topology containing $\mathscr{B}$. Hence, I guess it's likely that those topologies whose bases are $\mathscr{B}$ should be equal to $\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{B}$.

By the way, I have consulted the article
[Uniqueness of Topology and Basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712786/uniqueness-of-topology-and-basis) and one of comments (left by Henno) seems to justify my hunch and they mentioned any open set $O$ is a union of the elements of $\mathscr{B}$, so $O$ is already in the topology $\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{B}$, but how could they know $O$ can be written this way just by the definition of a basis? I mean, in Munkres' book, he mentioned in lemme 13.1, from my understanding, that $\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{B}=\left\{\cup_\alpha B_\alpha:B_\alpha \in \mathscr{B}\right\}$, as opposite to saying it holds for any topology with basis $\mathscr{B}$. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding at this point.

Any help is really appreciated!!

Comment: This is just a subtlety in the definitions Munkres uses. Notice in your first quote it says "a basis for **a** topology on $X$..." If we wish to speak about the basis for a particular given topology $\cal T$, then that is a set of basis elements $\cal B\subset \cal T$ such that $\cal T_{\cal B}=\cal T$. The uniqueness property is an immediate consequence to this definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say that topology $\mathcal T$ has basis $\mathcal B$ if $\mathcal T_{\mathcal B}=\mathcal T$.
Thus, it's immediate that if two topologies have the same basis then they coincide.

Saying that for every $x\in U$ there's a $B_x\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U$ is equivalent to saying that $U$ is the union of elements of $\mathcal B$, specifically $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}B_x$.

What you might be missing is that

> A set $\mathcal B$ of subsets of $X$ is a basis for a topology (meaning $\mathcal T_{\mathcal B}=\left\{\bigcup \mathcal D:\mathcal D\subseteq\mathcal B\right\} $ is a topology) if and only if the given conditions hold, i.e. $\forall x\in X\,\exists B\in\mathcal B: x\in B$ and $\forall x\in X\,\forall B_1,B_2\in\mathcal B\ x\in B_1\cap B_2\implies \exists B\in\mathcal B: x\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

Comment: So in Munkres's definition, he provided the definition of basis for a certain topology before really giving $X$ a topology.
Now if $\left( X,\mathscr{T}\right)$ is a topological space, then we say $\mathscr{T}$ has a basis $\mathscr{B}$ if $\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{B}=\mathscr{T}$, right?

Comment: Almost. He provided the definition of '*basis for a topology*' which name might be misleading as there's no particular topology mentioned in the definition, instead the basis will determine one.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the definition of topology as the collection of all open sets. Note now that every single open set can be written as the ***set-theoretic*** union of every basis element that contains a point $x \in U$, that is, $U = \bigcup_{x\in U} B_x $. Note now that, by the assumptions of a basis of a topology, you can always take two basis elements $B_1, B_2$ with nonempty intersection and find a third basis element in them (call it $B_3$). Nevertheless, the topology generated by the collection *without* $B_3$ and the one *with* $B_3$ is exactly the same and this comes from the fact that the set-theoretical union is not changing if we add a set that is already taken into account considering the sets $B_1$ and $ B_2$. This is the meaning for when Munkres writes that a basis for a topology is not like a basis for a vector space. So, from this point of view you can see that since the set-theoretic union of all (fixed) open sets is a unique object, then you can say that a basis determines the topology but not the converse.

Comment: Agree! A topology can have more than one basis. For example, let's say the real number $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the standard metric topology. Then $B_r\left(x\right)$, where $r,x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $B_q\left(x_q\right)$ ,where $q,x_q\in \mathbb{Q}$ both form bases for the metric topology, right?

Comment: Yes, consider that open balls in $\mathbb{R}$ are open intervals. Usually we take the ones with endpoints in $\mathbb{Q}$ (and radius whatever, also real) since we have, in this way, a basis formed by a countable collection of sets (so in a sense we have an easier-to-deal-with basis). More advanced remark: note that we can take the basis made by open intervals with rational endpoints thanks to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, but if you did not cover topics like linear continuum and connectedness, just forget about the last remark.